# Count(*) returns null on table with rows present

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from (select id, name from table1) as "t" limit 10 offset 10;
```

The above returns:

```
count(*)
________
```

If I run the following:

```
SELECT * from (select id, name from table1) as "t" limit 10 offset 10;
```

6 results.

```
id      name
1       name1
2       name2
.       .
.       .
.       .
6       name6
```

What is going on? I expect to see count(*): 6 because that is the number of rows present in the second query. All I am doing is counting them.

Comment: What is the output you actually want to see here?

Comment: I suspect the "offset" clause is causing the problem - but, in general, there are some things that don't quite make sense about the query, overall, anyway ..... if you just want a count of rows, then the query can just be SELECT COUNT(**) FROM table1.  Selecting from table1 in the subquery will give you no different result.  And then to have "limit" and/or "offset" clauses on a SELECT COUNT(*) query makes no sense - that query is always going to produce ONE, and only ONE, row as a result.  So, as I say, I suspect the "offset 10" is confusing things, because you'll only have 1 row anyway

Comment: @Craig actual query is much more complicated than selecting two columns from a single table. I put that in as an example. Not sure how the offset is the issue when select * from subquery returns 6 rows. Please clarify.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am expecting to see 6, the number of rows present in the second query.

Comment: ...so it is safe to say that the second query already meets your requirements?  If that's _not_ the case, then what _else_ do you want to see in the second query?

Comment: I want a count of the rows present in the second query. I thought I could get it by doing count(*). Not sure why I am seeing NULL.

Comment: @M.Nar - eric already answered your question (with the same thing that I suggested in my comment).  You cannot have an "offset" of 10 when the COUNT() query will only return a single row

Comment: You need to move the limit into the derived table https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=75fedf7cc9c8bac43db7bf90ab3083ec

Answer (score 2):

```
offset 10
```

because you have put this at the end, it means skip first 10 rows and the "select count" query only returns one row, so you get no result

Comment: Yes, this is the likely issue.